# Load more In ViewPager like ListView does when reaced last row

Tags: android, android-viewpager

All I want to implement load more in `viewPager` like `ListView` does when reached its last position, it loads more data and merges all previous one and new one. So how to implement in  `viewPager` when user reaches last position of fragment then load more 10(or any number of fragment)and get result like list view.
This is possible in case of `viewPager`?

Comment: why not? Everything is possible what is possible in an activity.

Comment: but how to get rid from this problem

Comment: Go to google and search about lazy list, get a demo and try to implement it.

Comment: You can use adapters in a viewpager like you do for a list view. Look for PagerAdapter.

Comment: Got your solution here ...check this out :)  https://github.com/lianghanzhen/EndlessViewPager/blob/master/library/src/com/lianghanzhen/endless/viewpager/EndlessPagerAdapter.java